# Restrict some system settings and options on Apple Watch Series 2

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I recently bought my father-in-law an Apple Watch Series 2, which I thought he would love, but we encounter a usage problem:

He seems to get the watch to reset itself to factory settings by mistake all the time!

Is there anyway to prevent him from inadvertently resetting the watch back to factory default settings?

I currently use watchOS 3, and as we speak I'm updating to watchOS 4.

Comment: You got your father an aWatch2, but then you say that ***you use*** watchOS 3 and you're in the process of upgrading to 4.  ***This is confusing***.  What is the watch and OS that you are having the issue with and *currently* working on.

Comment: Hi Allan,
Thank you for your response.
I used WatchOS3, and this was the OS on which i had this problem.

I did upgrade to WatchOS 4 yesterday, and haven’t used the AWatch2 since. So advice for both WatchOS 3 or 4, would be very helpful.
If there’s a solution that works only on one of the OSes, I'll use that OS. Even if it means downgrading back to WatchOS 3.

Thank you !
Eyal.